# Ubuntu 22.04.4 changing time zones stopped working

Tags: timezone

I've recently started having some weird problems with time zones on my laptop, despite the fact that it used to work just fine. First, at some point it stopped automatically changing time zone when I traveled. Now, I can't even change it manually. See, for example, what it says in the settings GUI [in this photo of my settings app, correctly recognizing I am in Chicago but saying that Chicago is PDT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qbTs.png). Sometimes, even when I am sitting in one place, my time zone randomly changes. Now it thinks Chicago is in PDT. If I manually change time zone and click the map on Chicago, it says PDT unless I click enough times, but even once it changes to CDT, nothing changes. Resetting the automatic time zone and automatic time options does not help.

Running `timedatctl` in my terminal correctly lists the time in CDT, but my clock displays it in PDT as do all of my apps, Google Calendar, etc.

Given how much I travel, this is quite annoying. It was nice when it changed automatically, a bit of a hassle when I had to change it manually, and now annoying that it doesn't change at all anymore. Any help is appreciated!